# Simplifying a logarithmic expression.

Tags: logarithms

I have:

$\log xy + \log 2x^2 - 0.5\log 4y^2$

The unlike terms make it hard to see what can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: The simplification probably comes from putting the x and y terms together. See Chinny84's answer on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Considering $x,y>0$ we can write the given expression as $$\log xy+\log 2x^2−0.5 \log 4y^2$$
$$=\log xy+\log 2x^2− \log (4y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$=\log xy+\log 2x^2−\log 2y$$
$$=\log \left(\frac{xy \times 2x^2}{2y}\right)$$
$$=\log x^3$$
$$=3\log x$$

Comment: how is $(4y^2)^{1/2}=2y$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Pardon, what do you mean?

Comment: hm i mean that $(4y^2)^{1/2}=2|y|$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Well, you're right. But I have mentioned at the beginning of my answer that $x,y>0$. For if any one of $x$ or $y$ $<0$, then $\log xy$ would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
\log (xy) = \log x + \log y
$$

Comment: it is only true for $x,y>0$

Comment: This is true but if either one was less than zero then $\log (xy)$ is an issue.

Comment: no with $\log(x)+\log(y)$ we get for both $x,y$ positive

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this we need to use the following rules for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+ \setminus \{ 0 \}$
$$ \ln(xy) = \ln x + \ln y, \ \ln(x^z) = z \ln x$$
For instance
$$0.5 \ln (4y^2) = \ln((4y^2)^{0.5}) = \ln (2y) = \ln 2 + \ln y$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: this rule is wrong also

Comment: Right you are!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint. You can use the following rules of logarithms:

$$\log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b),$$
$$\log(a/b) = \log(a)-\log(b),$$
$$\log(a^b) = b\log(a).$$

For instance, $\log(xy) + \log(2x^2) = \log((xy)(2x^2)) = \log(2x^3y)$.